# Is it possible to embed [bokeh] high level charts?

Tags: embed, bokeh

It seems most Bokeh embedding examples are using bokeh.plotting.figure object. Is it possible to embed a high level chart, like bokeh.charts.Bar or bokeh.charts.Scatter? Or is it possible to have convert a high level chart to a bokeh.plotting.figure object?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The User's Guide section on [Bokeh APIs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/concepts.html#interfaces) has a good run down of how all these parts fit together, that I would suggest reading.

The long-story-short: Regardless of what API you use, `bokeh.plotting` or `bokeh.charts`, the end result is always just a collection of the same low-level `bokeh.models` objects. You can can think of `bokeh.models` as very basic building blocks, and the other higher level APIs as conveniences that help you to assemble the building blocks more efficiently and correctly.

So, in that light, yes, it is perfectly fine to embed a `bokeh.chart` using exactly the same functions described in [Embedding Plots and Apps](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html).

---

The one thing I will add is that if you need to *update* the plot's data after the fact, in place, then the `bokeh.figure` API will probably be more straightforward. The mapping between your data, and what gets plotted is more direct. Things generated by `bokeh.charts` may transform your input data into entirely different forms before plotting (e.g. you give a series, and `Histogram` has to spit out coordinates for boxes—not the data you started with)

Comment: Thanks. Works fine for me using simple Scatter charts. Created a small example for others to follow at https://github.com/wyyang/bokeh_chart_django.